# how to replace ! to %21 in batch elegantly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i want to replace ! to %21(url encode) in batch,my code works,but not elegantly at all,any good ideal to finish the job in one line?

```
set pwd=!xxxxxxx
set pwd=%pwd:!=@21@%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !pwd:@21@=%%21!
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

Comment: Not sure but I guess you could also escape the `!` to replace like `^!` or `^^!`, so there might be no need to toggle delayed expansion...

Comment: @aschipfl,! no need to toggle delayed expansion,but % need...

Comment: Yes, sure, `%%` need to e doubled in batch (or escaped like `^%` directly in `cmd`)...

Comment: @aschipfl - It is impossible to escape `%` from the command line. But expansion of a variable can typically be prevented by including a `^` within the name. For example, `%var%` can effectively be escaped as `%^var%`, assuming there is no variable named `^var`, and your string is not quoted.

Comment: Original question restored. Please accept an answer if it has solved your problem. Ask another question, don't modify an existing question as it may render existing responses invalid which will cause respondents to lose interest in chasing a moving target.

Answer (score 4):

Not only can I not simplify your code, I argue that your code is not complex enough.

Your code will fail if any of the following occur

- The initial `pwd` value already contains `@21@`
- The initial `pwd` value already contains `%21`. Presumably you would want to encode the `%` as `%25`
- The initial value contains any poison character like `&`, `|`, `<`, `>`

Simply adding quotes cannot solve the poison character issue because presumably the value can also contain quotes. So a value like `"this & that" & the other thing` fails no matter how you quote it.

Here is robust code that can handle any set of characters except null, carriage return, and newline. I encode `!` as `%21`, and `%` as `%25`. No other encoding is done.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Set and display the initial value
set pwd=;"This & that" ^& the other thing! %%25 %%21 @A @Q @P @E
echo Before encoding:
set pwd
echo(


:: Encoding begins here
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  :: Protect @ as @A
  set "pwd=!pwd:@=@A!"

  :: Protect " as @Q
  set "pwd=!pwd:"=@Q!"

  :: Protect % as @P
  set "pwd=!pwd:%%=@P!"

  :: Encode ! as %21 in two steps
  set "pwd=%pwd:!=@E%"
  set "pwd=!pwd:@E=%%21!"

  :: Encode protected % as %25
  set "pwd=!pwd:@P=%%25!"

  :: Restore protected Q
  set "pwd=!pwd:@Q="!"

  :: Restore protected @
  set "pwd=!pwd:@A=@!"

  :: Display the result
  echo After encoding:
  echo !pwd!

endlocal
```

--OUTPUT--

```
Before encoding:
pwd=;"This & that" & the other thing! %25 %21 @A @Q @P @E

After encoding:
;"This & that" & the other thing%21 %2525 %2521 @A @Q @P @E
```

Sometimes you want to preserve the variable after the ENDLOCAL. This can easily be accomplished via FOR /F. Special syntax is required to disable both the EOL and DELIMS options.

I've removed all the comments to better show the amount of code required.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set pwd=;"This & that" ^& the other thing! %%25 %%21 @A @Q @P @E
echo Before encoding:
set pwd
echo(

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "pwd=!pwd:@=@A!"
set "pwd=!pwd:"=@Q!"
set "pwd=!pwd:%%=@P!"
set "pwd=%pwd:!=@E%"
set "pwd=!pwd:@E=%%21!"
set "pwd=!pwd:@P=%%25!"
set "pwd=!pwd:@Q="!"
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("!pwd:@A=@!") do (
  endlocal
  set "pwd=%%A"
)

echo After encoding:
set pwd
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
Before encoding:
pwd=;"This & that" & the other thing! %25 %21 @A @Q @P @E

After encoding:
pwd=;"This & that" & the other thing%21 %2525 %2521 @A @Q @P @E
```

Normally the simple FOR /F technique shown above only works when you start (and end) with delayed expansion disabled. Additional code would be needed to protect `!` when `%%A` is expanded and delayed expansion is enabled. But since you have already encoded your `!` as
`%21`, there is no problem if delayed expansion is enabled after ENDLOCAL.

Comment: new question,replace "="?

Comment: @jils2013 - That is nearly impossible to do with any kind of efficiency using pure batch. See http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1485 for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set pwd=!xxxxxxx
set pwd=%pwd:!=@21@%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !pwd:@21@=%%^21!
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

it will attempt to replace `%2` with the second argument to the script so you can use `%%^2` to avoid that.

Comment: tks,more rigorous...any idea to finish replacement in one set statment?

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke the .NET `System.Uri.EscapeUriString()` method via PowerShell, captured with a `for /f`, for a tidy one-liner.

```js
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell "[uri]::EscapeUriString('%pwd%')"`) do set "pwd=%%~I"
```

I guess it's up to you whether that qualifies as elegant.  *shrug*  In addition to [`[uri]::EscapeUriString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you might also play with [`[uri]::EscapeDataString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see which method offers the result you want.

Or a little faster performing, you could use some JScript hybrid code to perform JavaScript's [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your data.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off & setlocal

set "pwd=http://www.google.com/search?q=Hello world!&gws_rd=ssl"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%pwd%"') do set "pwd=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(!pwd!
endlocal

goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript

WSH.Echo(encodeURI(WSH.Arguments(0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to store different values in different variables keeping (important)  originals for future:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "pwd=!xxx"
set "pwX=%pwd:!=@21@%"
set pw
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo EDE !pwX:@21@=%%21!
set "pwdAux=!pwX:@21@=%%21!"
endlocal&set "pwX=%pwdAux%"
set pw
echo pwd %pwd%
echo pwX %pwX%
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\36125004.bat
pwd=!xxx
pwX=@21@xxx
EDE %21xxx
pwd=!xxx
pwX=%21xxx
pwd !xxx
pwX %21xxx

==>
```